# Votes and Deleted Answers

Tags: feature-request, voting, deleted-answers

Here is what happened, I had only 2 votes left today and I down voted an answer, a few moments later the owner of the answer deletes it and I "lost" my vote, I can't even undo it.

In these situations wouldn't be more appropriate to give the vote back? Since the question is deleted it doesn't matter if it has 10 up votes or 10 down votes, because it isn't being shown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will get your -1 rep back at the next [rep recalc](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2251/will-we-get-back-rep-points-lost-after-a-rep-recalc)*, which essentially starts everyone at 0 rep again and goes through the entire site and awards everyone their reputation for all (visible) posts.

*<sub>Rep recalc: also see: easter bunny, ponies, tooth fairy.</sub>

Comment: +1 for your footnote, but you can ask a mod for a recalc every time.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the post is not actually deleted... it's visible to 10k users, and it could get deleted, but later (definitely more than 24 hours later, when you already have more votes to spend)

Comment: and the person still loses their rep